# PHP - read directory and include all index.php's

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, include

I have a directory 'modules' which will contain different modules for the web app. How can I include all the index.php's from every module in the 'modules' folder?

So basically the same as how Wordpress loads its plugins.

This is the structure of the 'modules' folder:

```
 [modules]
      [some-module]
           - index.php
           - functions.php
           - other.php
      [another-module]
           - index.php
           - stuff.php
      [someother]
           - index.php
           - script.js
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do this?

```
<?php

$indexes = glob('modules/*/index.php');

foreach ($indexes as $path) {
    require_once $path;
}
```